# Not able to trigger the onkeydown event on an editable <p:selectOneMenu

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu, onkeyup

I'm trying to implement keyboard arrow navigation on a datatable.

For that manner I'm adding the event *onkeydown* in each column component of that *datatable* and then it calls a JavaScript function that will evaluate if the pressed button was an arrow key. If it is, it will *focus()* or *click()* the next or the previous component. Everything was working fine until that component is an editable i.e. on the .

Sample code:

```
<p:column id="column3" headerText="column test">
    <p:cellEditor >
        <f:facet name="output" >
            <h:outputText value="#{beneficiary.lista.selectedValue}" styleClass="required" />
        </f:facet>

        <f:facet name="input">
            <p:selectOneMenu id="sel3"  onkeydown="alert('down')" onkeyup="alert('up')" onchange="alert('change')"
                value="#{beneficiary.lista.selectedKey}" filter="true"
                filterMatchMode="contains"   required="true" editable="true">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel=" " itemValue=" "  />
                        <f:selectItems
                            value="#{beneficiary.lista.possibleValues}"
                            var="selection" itemValue="#{selection.key}"
                            itemLabel="#{selection.value}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </f:facet>
    </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>
```

Here, I'm able to make the *click()* and gain the focus. I'm able to switch between the values from the list and that will trigger the *onchange* event. However when I click on it again to edit, neither *onkeyup* nor *onkeydown* are triggered.

**UPDATE:**
As per suggested, I did inspect the element after writing something there ("Simple Test") and this was what I got:

```
<div class="ui-cell-editor-output" style="display: block;">
    <span class="required">Simple Test</span>
</div>
<div class="ui-cell-editor-input" style="display: none;">
    <div class="ui-selectonemenu ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" id="contentForm:newtable:0:sel3">
        <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
            <input name="contentForm:newtable:0:sel3_focus" id="contentForm:newtable:0:sel3_focus" type="text" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
            <select name="contentForm:newtable:0:sel3_input" tabIndex="-1" id="contentForm:newtable:0:sel3_input" onkeydown="alert('down')" onkeyup="alert('up')" onchange="alert('change');">
                <option value=" "></option>
                <option value="OPTION1">Option 1 </option>
                <option value="OPTION2">Option 2</option>
                <option value="OPTION3">Option 3</option>
                </select>
        </div>
        <input name="contentForm:newtable:0:sel3_editableInput" class="ui-selectonemenu-label ui-inputfield ui-corner-all" type="text" value="Simple Test">
        <div class="ui-selectonemenu-trigger ui-state-default ui-corner-right">
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-c"></span>
        </div>
    /div>
</div>
```

Did any of you face similar problem in the past? Any solutions/suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

*The reason is not JSF specific, but more how firing events in a browser works:*

- *select tags cannot accept keyboard-types input, so they won't fire keydown|up events, but surely they respond to changes, like when you select one or more.*
- *for instance, add a `<p:inputText onkeydown="alert('down')" onkeyup="alert('up')" />` to your JSF page (same with generic `h:inputText`) and you will see them being fired*
- *remember that only on onkeyup, the new value is set (in input fields, of course), onkeydown the previous (!) value can be read.*

*Hope this helps a bit. :-)*

**Edit:** TIL: A simple HTML test works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML onkeydown/onykeyup test</title>
</head>
<body>
<body>
<form>
<select onchange="alert('change')" onkeydown="alert('keydown')" onkeyup="alert('keyup')">
<option>Value 1</option>
<option>Value 2</option>
<option>Value 3</option>
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

If I use keyboard, the following events fire in order:

- keydown
- keyup
- change

Strange that your PF 6.1 (?) test did not work.

Comment: Well, I understand what you said. However, if it's possible to make a <p:selectOneMenu editable, we should be able to track what the user writes on that component with the onkeyup/down event.

If I switch from <p:selectOneMenu to <h:selectOneMenu, both events start to get triggered... but on the other hand I'm not able to edit or filter...

Comment: Plus, I have checked the PrimeFaces documentation (https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_1.pdf) and on the page 463 it says that onkeyup/down are SelectOneMenu's attributes.

Comment: Then they should fire. I made a simple HTML test, they are firing. See edit of my answer.

Are you using 6.1? I have 6.0 (CE) here.

Comment: **1) Are you using 6.1?** I have 6.0 (CE) here.

**2) What does the generated HTML output look like?**

Comment: Real simple html != PrimeFaces selectOneMenu... Do a view source and of the html and compare!

Comment: Sure, I know that JSF is a web component language and not yet-another template language. What I also asked in **2)** is for the same thing, compare output with my example; are all attributes on *select* tag; and is it valid (X)HTML?

Comment: First of all thanks for your attention guys.

Yes, I'm using 6.1. I have updated this question with the HTML code provided after inspecting this p:selectOneMenu. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it with override with that class:

```
package org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu;
...
public class SelectOneMenuRenderer extends SelectOneRenderer{
...
    protected void encodeInput(.....){
        ...
        writer.writeAttribute("class", "ui-helper-hidden-accessible", null);    
        writer.startElement("input", null);
        writer.writeAttribute("id", focusId, null);
        writer.writeAttribute("name", focusId, null);
        writer.writeAttribute("type", "text", null);
        writer.writeAttribute("autocomplete", "off", null);

       //add this line
        if (menu.getOnkeydown() != null) writer.writeAttribute("onkeydown", menu.getOnkeydown(), null);
        ....

    }
...
}
```